# Property 'searchText' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

There is following variable in class:

```
public searchText: string;
```

When strict mode is enabled in TypeScript, I see the following error:

```
Property 'searchText' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor
```

In fact when I put `''` like:

```
public searchText: string = "";
```

It solves my problem, but why if default definition string is alreadyempty string;

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `but why if default definition string is alreadyempty string;`. If you don't set a value, the default in JS is `undefined`. So you have a property (`searchText`) which is defined as `string` (and according to the type system can't be `undefined`) which will be `undefiend` at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you dont assign value to a variable in javascript then variables have 'undefined' value in it.

so here if you do like this

```
public searchText: string;
```

then `searchText=undefined` and not an empty string. You can do console log you will get undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can "mark" attribute how nullable.

```
public searchText?: string;
```

Or change tsconfig.ts to accept attributes no initialized.
Remove comment in this line and set false.

```
"strictPropertyInitialization": false
```